# executing 2 functions in one click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I execute 2 functions at the same time. In the code snippet below with the onclick, I get the `id` of the parent Div and then execute a function using the `id`,

```
<div id="selDe">
<input type="radio" class="ger" id="num1" checked><label for="num1">
<input type="radio" class="ger" id="num2"><label for="num2">
</div>
<div id="selRe" >
<input type="radio" class="ger" id="num1" checked><label for="num1">
<input type="radio" class="ger" id="num2"><label for="num2">
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(".ger").on({
    click:function(){
        var pid = $(this).parent().attr("id");  //get the name of the div parent
        $("#"+pid+" .ger").on({   
//execute the function, but it just works after the next click
            click: function () {
                var showV = this.id.slice(3);
                alert(showV)
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible in JS

Comment: ID should always be unique....that is why it is called "ID"

Comment: I think you mean "in one click handler," not "at the same time." This is absolutely possible.

Comment: Is your question "is it possible to call one function from another"? Or I'm missing some important part?

Comment: yeah, I mean in one click handler

Comment: @ Alexei Levenkov yes

Comment: binding a click event in a click event is generally a bad idea unless you also unbind the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('div[id^=sel]').on('click', '.ger, div[id^=sel] .ger', function () {
    var pid = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    alert(pid);
    var showV = this.id.slice(3);
    alert(showV);
});
```